# -webkit-line-clamp is not cutting as it should

Tags: css

I'm setting up a banner and are using webkit-box (-webkit-line-clamp, -webkit-box-orient, overflow, text-overflow) to hide put ellipsis after 4 lines and hide everything below. The ellipsis shows up at the end of the fourth row but the text continues after that for ane whole row and thhe top of the row after.

I have been fiddeling around with it by changing properties in elements and googling for a solution but I'm coming up short and I need some help to figure out what's causing this in my code.
Code for the element:

```
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    line-height: 1.2;
```

Comment: Without a proper [reprex] we can only guess.

Comment: I'm guessing you just need overflow: hidden;